How can I go back neglecting seach params with react-router-dom?
Now I have this => navigate(-1); which is part of a button that navigates back, and here's the function fired when the user clicks the button:
const handleClick = async (e: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {    
  try {
      //  go back is confirmed
      navigate(-1);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // go back is cancelled
  }
}

but the situation is that the user can navigate though many pages and the history will be like this:
"/main" => "chat?page=1" => "chat?page=2" => "chat?page=3"
and if the user in page 3 and clicked on the back button, he will go back to page 2. How can I avoid all this page parameter and go directly from "/chat?page=3" to "/main"?
I tried removing the params using setSearchParams but it ended up moving the user to a new page and the stack became like this:
"/main" => "/chat?page=1" => "/chat?page=2" => "/chat?page=3" => "/chat"

Make all the navigations that update the page search parameter redirects (e.g. REPLACE) instead of forward (e.g. PUSH) actions. This will maintain the history stack in such a way that any back navigation (e.g. POP) goes back to the expected page.
See useSearchParams:

The setSearchParams function works like navigate, but only for the
search portion of the URL. Also note that the second arg to
setSearchParams is the same type as the second arg to navigate.

Example:



Location
Action
Type
History Stack




"/main"
navigate({  pathname: "/chat",  search: "?page=1",});
PUSH
["/main", "/chat?page=1"]


"/chat?page=1"
setSearchParams(  searchParams => {    searchParams.set("page", 2);    return searchParams;  },  { replace: true },);
REPLACE
["/main", "/chat?page=2"]


"/chat?page=2"
setSearchParams(  searchParams => {    searchParams.set("page", 3);    return searchParams;  },  { replace: true },);
REPLACE
["/main", "/chat?page=3"]


"/chat?page=3"
navigate(-1);
POP
["/main"]




ok I agree but how can I generalize that? this back button is implemented in many page so I might have a stack like this
"/main" => "chat?page=1" => "chat?page=2" => "chat?page=3" ,
"/main" => "test?page=1" => "test?page=2" => "test?page=3"  or
"/main" => "rules?page=1" => "rules?page=2" => "rules?page=3" ....... and so on
so implementing reach page with it's path name will be hard

@Nou What am I missing here? Wouldn't any back button just call navigate(-1)? The back button doesn't have anything to do with how any specific page manages the search params, they just need to redirect instead of push so when a POP finally happens the UI navigates back to the page you want.
